# このスクリプトのエラーをどうすればいいのか教えてください。

Tags: c#, unity3d

[image: このスクリプトエラー]

C#です。どうか答えてくださいおねがいします。

Comment: 画面キャプチャではなく、文字で表示されている情報は「文字」として質問文に記入してください。

Answer (score 0):

とにかく、"Vector"という定義されていない変数名(?)を使うのをやめましょう。（たぶん、Vectorに似た名前の変数か何かを使うべきなのだと思います）

そうすれば、「現在のコンテキストに"Vector"という名前は存在しません。」というエラーが解消できます。